# VBA Automation of RogueWave HostAccess

Tags: vba, excel, session, rogue-wave

I am looking to open a session of RogueWave HostAccess in order to automate via SendKeys Functions.  Code provided by company is listed below, but when ran the code opens a new widow of the terminal emulator, but freezes at GetObject() [2nd Line].

Error received: Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action.  Run-time error 429 - ActiveX component can't create object.

Code Provided by RogueWave:

```
Rem Define the variable HostAccess as the data type object.
Rem This represents the HostAccess application when used for
Rem OLE automation
Dim HostAccess
Rem Create an OLE object that corresponds to HostAccess.
Rem We will use this object to invoke
Rem published automation methods.
Set HostAccess = GetObject("", "Session.Setting")
Rem Start a session with the given name
result = HostAccess.LoadSession("TEST.SES", "", True)
Rem Once HostAccess has loaded, tell it to print something
Rem on the terminal window.
result = HostAccess.ScriptExec("print ""hello world""")
Rem Close the HostAccess session
HostAccess.EndSession
Rem Unload/Exit HostAccess
HostAccess.Unload
```

Source:http://docs.roguewave.com/HostAccess/7.40j/HostAccessUserGuide.pdf

Thanks,

Comment: Wow, welcome to 1980 with RogueWave's sample code.  Do you need to attach to a running session or are you trying to create a new one?

Comment: I could work around either scenario.  Originally I was working with creating a new session.

Comment: If you need a new session, try replacing `Set HostAccess = GetObject("", "Session.Setting")` with `Set HostAccess = CreateObject("Session.Setting")`.

Comment: I did try changing the GetObject to CreateObject, but still receive the same error that it is unable to create the object.  The HostAccess window does launch which leads be to believe the HostAccess is not properly communicating back that it is window is opened correctly.